# jQuery break out of $.on that is within $.each

Tags: javascript, jquery, break

I need to iterate over an AJAX response and break out of an event handler when a condition is met. I'm having trouble with this code:

```
$.each(response, function(i, v) {

    // create mapbox object
    var map = L.mapbox.map('map', v.map_embed_id, {
        zoomAnimation: false
    });

    var polygonLayer = L.mapbox.featureLayer().loadURL('https://a.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/' + v.map_embed_id + '/features.json?access_token=abcde').addTo(map);

    polygonLayer.on('ready', function() {
        var layer = leafletPip.pointInLayer(latlng, polygonLayer, true);

        if (layer.length) {
            // this is where I need to break out of $.on 
            // and the current $.each iteration
        }
    });
});
```

I know `return false` would break out of the `$.each` iteration but this is more difficult since I need to break out of the `$.on` event handler. What can I do? Could I use a `trigger` maybe?

Comment: Are you sure you need to bind the event for each iteration of `each`? That looks a little suspect, and is probably what I would tackle.

Comment: can use [stop propagation](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopimmediatepropagation/) for event handler and `return false` for each

Comment: Why are you binding a ready event? What do you think it does?

Comment: The each will be done LONG before any of those events get triggered. So much wrong here.

Comment: @KevinB, I'm binding a ready event simply because I'm following a `Leaflet` tutorial. What do you suggest I do instead?

Comment: Can i see said tutorial? The "ready" event is a special event that correlates to the DOMContentLoaded event. It's usually not used for anything else. Is `polygonLayer` a jquery object, or is it something else

Comment: Sure - [here you go](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/example/v1.0.0/fit-map-to-markers/)

Comment: Ok yea that isn't a jquery object. I think you should put the each inside of that event bindings, there's no reason to bind the event more than once.

Comment: I'm going to adjust the code in my question to show you more of what I was doing.

Comment: If you're looping and creating layers, you'll need to differentiate between the layers in the each, your current code doesn't demonstrate that.

Comment: Also, you need to break away from the idea of being able to break out of the loop from within the event, the loop will be done long before any of the events happen, making it impossible.

Comment: Gotcha, understood, `polygonLayer` loads a unique map on each iteration, or at least that was my intention. Hope that makes a little more sense now as to what I was attempting.

Comment: will layer.length ever be falsy?

Comment: No, it won't return a layer object at all if it doesn't exist.

Comment: I guess i just don't understand what your goal here is then. I can say for sure that what you are currently doing simply isn't possible, so you'll have to come up with another way to accomplish your goal.

Comment: Are you just opening maps by id until you find one that has data?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58009/discussion-between-jared-eitnier-and-kevin-b).

Comment: @KevinB thx for your help. I fixed this all using recursion.

Comment: Make sure you post an answer demonstrating what worked to help future visitors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Kevin B's advice to use recursion, this is how I fixed my code to make it work.

```
getMapsList().done(function(maps) {
    getMapboxMap(maps, geocode);
});

function getMapboxMap(maps, geocode) {

    var map_params   = maps[0];
    var map_embed_id = map_params.map_embed_id;

    if (maps.length > 0)
        maps.shift();

    // create mapbox object
    var map = L.mapbox.map('map', map_embed_id, {
        zoomAnimation: false
    });

    // create marker of address entered
    L.mapbox.featureLayer({
        type: 'Feature',
        geometry: {
            type: 'Point',
            coordinates: [
                geocode.location.lng,
                geocode.location.lat
            ]
        },
        properties: {
            title: address,
            'marker-size': 'medium',
            'marker-color': '#f44',
            'marker-symbol': 'star'
        }
    }).addTo(map);

    // create polygon layer and add to map from map's geojson
    var polygonLayer = L.mapbox.featureLayer().loadURL('https://a.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/' + map_embed_id + '/features.json?access_token=pk.eyJ1IjoiZW5nbGVzaWRldGVycml0b3JpZXMiLCJhIjoiekFIU0NlayJ9.rE9XdicgXc9aIiXJ9yn68w').addTo(map);

    // after polygon layer has been added to map
    polygonLayer.on('ready', function() {

        // featureLayer.getBounds() returns the corners of the furthest-out markers,
        // and map.fitBounds() makes sure that the map contains these.
        map.fitBounds(polygonLayer.getBounds());

        // create a latLng object based on lat/lng of address entered
        var latlng = L.latLng(geocode.location.lat, geocode.location.lng);

        // create point in layer object
        var layer = leafletPip.pointInLayer(latlng, polygonLayer, true);

        if (layer.length) {
            // found it
            return false;
        } else {
            if (maps.length > 0) {
                getMapboxMap(maps, geocode);
            }
        }
    });
}

function getMapsList() {
    return $.get('/utility/territories/maps-list');
}
```